# Setup Google Analytics 4 property from 2 different tags

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

To measure my top-level domain and my subdomain I have installed 2 different Google tags in each of them and use 2 Google Analytics properties (Say `Site` & `App`). I am looking to setup a 3rd Google Analytics property (Say `Commons`) that combines the data from both tags.

My GA4 structure goes as below

- Site property - tag 1
- App property - tag 2
- Commons property - tag 1 & tag 2 (trying to achieve this)

I don't want to use a single tag on both domains as I would like to retain the individual property views. Is this possible and how do I achieve this?

Note: Combining tags in tag manager destroys individual views. Connected tags with cross domain setup didn't work for me.